# Do i need to use a method or can I simply pass an operation when it is changed?

Tags: java, methods, operation

Is it possible for me to pass the operation string back from when a `+`, `-` or `*` operation occurs so that it saves it as operation and then I can move on to when I press `=` or is this simply impossible?

#### Code part 1:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent calculate)
    {
    JButton operand = (JButton) calculate.getSource();
    String flip = operand.getLabel();
    String operation = "";
    System.out.println(operation);
    String value1 = (box1.getText());
    String value2 = (box2.getText());
    box1.setText(box1.getText() + operand.getLabel());

    if (flip.equals("C"))
        {
        box2.setText("");
        box1.setText("");
        }

    if (flip.equals("!"))
        {
        int intValueNeg = Integer.parseInt(value1);
        int negateIntValue = intValueNeg * (-1);
        String negativeInt = Integer.toString(negateIntValue);
        box1.setText(negativeInt);
        }

    if (flip.equals("+")) 
        {
        box2.setText(value1);
        box1.setText("");
        operation = operand.getLabel();
        }

    if (flip.equals("-"))    
        {
        box2.setText(value1);
        box1.setText("");
        operation = operand.getLabel();
        }

    if (flip.equals("*"))
        {
        box2.setText(value1);
        box1.setText("");
        operation = operand.getLabel();
        }

    if (flip.equals("=") && operation.equals("+"))
        {
        int intValue1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
        int intValue2 = Integer.parseInt(value2); 
        int totalValue = intValue1 + intValue2;
        String totalResult = Integer.toString(totalValue);
        box1.setText(totalResult);
        box2.setText("0");
        } 

    if (flip.equals("=") && operation.equals("-"))
        {
        int intValue1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
        int intValue2 = Integer.parseInt(value2); 
        int totalValue = intValue2 - intValue1;
        String totalResult = Integer.toString(totalValue);
        box1.setText(totalResult);
        box2.setText("0"); 
        } 

    if (flip.equals("=") && operation.equals("*"))
        {
        int intValue1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
        int intValue2 = Integer.parseInt(value2); 
        int totalValue = intValue1 * intValue2;
        String totalResult = Integer.toString(totalValue);
        box1.setText(totalResult);
        box2.setText("0"); 
        }                      
    }
}
```

#### Code part 2:

```
box2 = new JTextField (10);
b.add(box2);

Blackbelt.add(a, BorderLayout.NORTH);
Blackbelt.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
Blackbelt.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Why do you only provide half the code?

Comment: Don't compare strings using `==`, use `equals()` methods

Comment: Sorry i thought i provided everything that was required, i dont think its the equals() that is the problem because when i set operation to +, -, or * manually it works perfectly i just don't know how to get it to set when one of they keys is pressed

Comment: `flip == "anything"` will absolutely not work in Java

Comment: howcome it won't work could you please explain?

Comment: First, you settle down. Then, you pay attention to the people who tell you to use `equals()` rather than `==`. Java has an optimization where `==` works for literal string values, and I'm guessing that's what you mean by "setting manually."

Comment: Sorry i have been at this for ages, String operation = "-"; that is what i meant by setting it manually, i'm just not sure what to do with equals() will this keep the value for operation?

Answer (score 1):

To check strings for equality, you should always use the `equals()` method. Taking a piece of your code, it would look like this:

```
if (flip.equals("-"))
{
    box2.setText(value1);
    box1.setText("");
    operation = "-";
}
```

If `flip` can possibly be null, you could re-arrange the test to look like this:

```
if ("-".equals(flip))
```

Java has an optimization, where it reuses literal string values. So if you write something like this, the two variables point to the same physical object, and `==` will return true.

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "foo";
```

However, if you're reading a string value from a GUI (which it looks like you're doing), this is not a literal value, and is not optimized in that way. It's a good habit to *always* use `equals()` to check for equality of objects, and only use `==` for primitive values.

Comment: Thanks i have changed all of it to include equals however the calculator itself still does not work correctly, I want it to change what operation that is relevant i.e  +, - or * is clicked I want it so that when it goes to the bottom if statements it will choose the correct calculation to carry out will upload the new code now

Answer (score 0):

Always use the Strategy design pattern for operations like this below.

//StrategyExample test application

public class StrategyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context;
        // Three contexts following different strategies
        context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyAdd());
        int resultA = context.executeStrategy(3, 4);
        context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategySubtract());
        int resultB = context.executeStrategy(3, 4);
        context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyMultiply());
        int resultC = context.executeStrategy(3, 4);
    }
}

//The classes that implement a concrete strategy should implement this
// The context class uses this to call the concrete strategy
public interface Strategy {
    int execute(int a, int b);
}

//Implements the algorithm using the strategy interface
public class ConcreteStrategyAdd implements Strategy {
        public int execute(int a, int b) {
            System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategyA's execute");
            return a + b; // Do an addition with a and b
        }
}

public class ConcreteStrategySubtract implements Strategy {
    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategyB's execute()");
        return a - b; // Do a subtraction with a and b
    }
}

public class ConcreteStrategyMultiply implements Strategy {
    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategyC's execute()");
        return a * b; // Do a multiplication with a and b
    }
}

//Configured with a ConcreteStrategy object and maintains a reference to a Strategy object
public class Context {
    private Strategy strategy;

```
// Constructor
public Context(Strategy strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
}

public int executeStrategy(int a, int b) {
    return strategy.execute(a, b);
}
```

}